# How to create filter chips with the single selected method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a filter page. I use filter chips to filter the products.

Created filter chips with 4 options. But it works in a multi-selective manner. I want a filter chip with a single selective method.
How to achieve this?

[image]

How to make the above image single-selected?

code:

```
final items3 = [
    "All",
    "0-2 Years",
    "2-4 Years",
    "5-7 Years",
    "8-13 Years",
    "14+ Years"
  ];
  late List<String> age = [items3.first];

Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text('AGE',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                              color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              letterSpacing: 0.8,
                            )),
                      ]),
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 20),
                  child: Wrap(
                    spacing: 8,
                    runSpacing: 15,
                    children: items3
                        .map(
                          (e) => FilterChip(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              selectedColor: const Color(0xff6fedf6),
                              label: Container(
                                height: 46,
                                width: 80,
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Text(e),
                              ),
                              labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 14,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                                ),
                              ),
                              selected: age.contains(e),
                              onSelected: (bool value) {
                                filter(age: '0-2');
                                if (age.contains(e)) {
                                  age.remove(e);
                                } else {
                                  age.add(e);
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                              }),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: instead of a list `List<String> age` use `String age`

Comment: If I give "String age;", I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, use a `String` instead of a `List<String>`:

```
late String age = items3.first;
```

```
onSelected: (bool value) {
  // filter(age: '0-2');
  setState(() {
    age = e;
  });
}),
```